# SQL Server statement throws ErrorCode 208

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I am developing an SQL query, which is compatible for Oracle SQL and SQL Server. I have the following working Oracle SQL code, which generates the top 15 consumers which bought products by Visa:

```
SELECT ddo.code as "Data Owner", ROUND((count(ffp.id) / (select count(ffp2.id) from Payments_Table ffp2 join PAY_CHARACTERISTICS dmc2 on ffp2.characteristics_id = dmc2.id where dmc2.visa_flag = 1) * 100),2) as "% UP"
    FROM Customer_Table ddo
    JOIN Payment_Table ffp ON ddo.id = ffp.data_owner_id
    JOIN PAY_CHARACTERISTICS dpc ON ffp.characteristics_id = dpc.id
    WHERE dpc.visa_flag = 1
    GROUP BY ddo.code
ORDER BY count(ffp.id) desc
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 15 ROWS ONLY;
```

When I compile this, Oracle SQL generates a correct top 15.
But SQL Server throws the following exception:

> Error: Invalid object name 'DIM_DATA_OWNER'. SQLState:  S0002
>   ErrorCode: 208

So there is something wrong with the query. I need to modify this so it works on SQL Server and also still works on Oracle. Any help?

Comment: Message is very clear. You need to use TOP in subquery if you want to use ORDER BY

Comment: Move out the inner select, do select top 15.

Comment: Indeed Stanislovakas, top doesn't work on oracle.

Comment: It has to be Oracle and SQL Server compatible? Try ANSI SQL's FETCH FIRST 15 ROWS ONLY (after order by clause). Newer Oracle has it, and perhaps newer SQL Server too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you can't have `order by` in the inner queries. It can only be applied on the entire result-set.

```
    with x as 
    (SELECT ddo.code as "Customer", count(ffp.id) as cntffp,
    ROUND((count(ffp.id) / (select count(ffp2.id) from PAYMENTS_TABLE ffp2  
    join PAY_CHARACTERISTICS dmc2 on ffp2.characteristics_id = dmc2.id
    where dmc2.VISA_FLAG = 1) * 100),2) as "% UP"
    FROM CUSTOMERS_TABLE ddo 
    JOIN PAYMENTS_TABLE ffp ON ddo.id = ffp.data_owner_id
    JOIN PAY_CHARACTERISTICS dpc ON ffp.characteristics_id = dpc.id
    WHERE dpc.bulked_flag = 'N'
    GROUP BY ddo.code)
    , y as (select *, row_number() over(order by cntffp desc) as rn from x)
    select Customer, "% Up" from y 
    where rn <= 15
```

Comment: SQL Server has not `rownum` column

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ANSI SQL's `FETCH FIRST` works with both Oracle and SQL Server these days?

```
SELECT ddo.code as "Customer", ROUND((count(ffp.id) / (select count(ffp2.id) from PAYMENTS_TABLE ffp2 join PAY_CHARACTERISTICS dmc2 on ffp2.characteristics_id = dmc2.id where dmc2.VISA_FLAG = 1) * 100),2) as "% UP"
FROM CUSTOMERS_TABLE ddo 
JOIN PAYMENTS_TABLE ffp ON ddo.id = ffp.data_owner_id
JOIN PAY_CHARACTERISTICS dpc ON ffp.characteristics_id = dpc.id
WHERE dpc.bulked_flag = 'N'
GROUP BY ddo.code
ORDER BY count(ffp.id) desc
FETCH FIRST 15 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: this works in oracle, but in mssql I get following error:

Error: Invalid usage of the option FIRST in the FETCH statement.
SQLState:  S0002
ErrorCode: 153

Comment: Which SQL Server version?

Comment: I used the jar from sqljdbc 4.4.0

Comment: SQL Server 2012 or 2014, I believe, is needed.

Comment: Odd, what does your SQL Server documentation say?